# Spring data Repositiry does not check for isNew(entity) on classes that are marked to be cascaded under the main entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a parent class (for ease of understanding and running on your locals i have simplified the class structure)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_a")
public class EntityA implements Serializable, Persistable<Integer> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_b_id")
    private EntityB entityB;

    /* Getter and Setter */

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_b")
public class EntityB implements Serializable, Persistable<String> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entityB")
    private EntityA entityA;

    /* Getters and Setters */

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }

}
```

When I try to persist the new entity EntityA using the following spring data repository:

```
public interface EntityARepository extends JpaRepository<EntityA, Integer> {
}
```

it only checks for `isNew` on `EntityA` but ignores the `isNew` on `EntityB` and I keep getting `primary key constraint` errors on the persist operation

The reason why I am implementing the `Persistable` interface is because the EntityB is actually something that can be repeated quite a few times so I would like to check for its existence and set the `isNew` boolean accordingly before its saved

How do I make the spring repository take into account the `isNew` property of the child class as well that is marked to be cascaded

Comment: Did you also set entityB.entityA = entityA? What do you mean by "EntityB is actually something that can be repeated"? Is it a One-to-One or One-to-Many relationship?

Comment: Yes I do set entityB.entityA = entityA and its one-to-one but there is some business logic in EntityB's isNew() method that does a lot more than just returning boolean. I didnt want to post all of that in here but it edits the ID of both parent and child in that logic. So relationship is one-to-one.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to modify the entity while it's being saved. Is there a business reason for manually setting the ID's? Why not let the database do it, or set it to a UUID in each constructor.

Comment: Yes, the ID's come from a JSON from an external source. And if a duplicate ID is recognized for EntityB then we have to modify that ID plus the ID of the Parent. I know a work-around to it for now but I was wondering how I can make spring's isNew do it for me

Comment: to put it simply, if isNew gets called on cascaded(child) entities the problem gets solved.

Comment: Spring Data JPA uses JPA. `Persistable` and `isNew` is a Spring concept that helps Spring decide whether to call JPA`EntityManager`'s `persist` or `merge`. However, the concept of cascading is pure JPA, and JPA does not know what `Persistable` is. In short, what you're asking cannot be done. You need to `save` the related `EntityB` manually.

Comment: @crizzis Aah damn it!! So are you saying that I manually persist the EntityB and disable the cascading so that JPA doesnt try to persist it again?

Comment: Well, if you know that `EntityB` has all its properties configured properly (including the id), and you're fine with its state overriding the db state, you could simply force a merge (e.g. by overriding `isNew` in `EntityA` to always return false, or by overriding the `EntityARepository.save()` method to always call `EnttyManager.merge()`).

Comment: However, it seems to me you're overthinking this. Since you say you're already checking if `EntityB` exists, why not simply retrieve the existing managed `EntityB` instance, and assign it to `EntityA.entityB` instead?

Comment: Second option seems correct but its trying to persist it even when I try to assign a EntityB to EntityA and I get primary key constraint exception

Comment: @crizzis I started using entity-manager to handle the whole operation and it gives me the exact behavior as there is no fight/mix between spring and hibernate there is no confusion/consequence